# Affine Transform recreation in android?

Tags: android, transactions

Need reproduce the affice transform in android device. i took the affine transform from the `getMatrix()` method

```
 float[] matrixValues = new float[9];
        matrix.getValues(matrixValues);

        float a = matrixValues[0];
        float b = matrixValues[3];
        float tx = matrixValues[2];
        float c = matrixValues[1];
        float d = matrixValues[4];
        float ty = matrixValues[5];
```

i recreate the angle using

```
 float rAngle = Math.round(Math.atan2(v[Matrix.MSKEW_X], v[Matrix.MSCALE_X]) * (180 / Math.PI));
```

but the problem is that i need to apply

```
  setPivotX(0);
  setPivotY(0);
```

for getting the position of the image correct, why is this happening?

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve? what do you need `rAngle` for? what is `getMatrix` called on? a View, Canvas, Transormation?

Comment: @pskink :  i am sending the affine transform to ios . they are not able to reproduce the same effect here .  i think the problem is related with the point of rotation for android it is (0,0). but for ios it is the center of view . how to over come this?

Comment: so use setPivotX/Y with a center of your view

Comment: @pikink: if I set that working fine. What should I do when I sent to iOS.?

Comment: i have no idea about iOS

Comment: Is it possible to get the getmatix based on centre of a view in android?

Comment: it makes no sense to "get the getmatix based on centre of a view"

Comment: For Android. Everything is based on origin (0,0). R8?.